# How can i get the disconnect call cause without using logcat files?

Tags: android, call, logcat, disconnect

I need to retrieve the disconnect call cause in android,i tried to use logcat files and it provide a good result but the problem is that we must root phones having api > 16 in order to access logcat files so i want to know if there is another way to get disconnect call cause without using logcat files ?

Comment: Also see [Retrieving detailed disconnect cause value from telephony framework](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-contrib/mQvNL695z_0/p1QveOWPck4J).

Comment: @jww the problem is that the telephony framework is not accessible !!